# How do I evaluate $\log_3(x^2 − 36) − \log_3(x − 6)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The questions ask to combine the expression using the laws of logarithms.
$$\log_3(x^2 − 36) − \log_3(x − 6)$$

I got $$\frac{\log_3(x^2-36)}{\log_3(x-6) } $$ but my book says that is not correct.

Comment: Did you remember that $\log\frac ab = \log a - \log b$? Your expression has the latter form.

Comment: No. I don't understand.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Well if I make the expression a quotient it still is incorrect according to my book.

Comment: Perhaps you should say in your question what quotient you got. Otherwise nobody will know how to correct your error. Or perhaps there is no error and your book is mistaken.  But we will never know if you don't tell us.

Comment: log3 (x^2-36) / log3(x-6)

Comment: $ \log a - \log b $ is equal to $\log\frac ab$. It is not equal to $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that $\log a - \log b$ can't *possibly* be equal to $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$, because subtraction is not the same thing as division.

Comment: I think you need to say more than just subtraction is not division. For example $4/2=4-2=2.$

Comment: @RR Implicit universal quantifier. Though it would have been good to make that quantifier explicit.

Answer (score 8):

Recall that $$\log a-\log b=\log\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)$$

Then using this principle, $$\log_3(x^2 − 36) − \log_3(x − 6)=\log_3\left(\dfrac{x^2-36}{x-6}\right)=\underbrace{\log_3\left(\dfrac{(x+6)(x-6)}{x-6}\right)}_{\text{Here the } (x-6)\text{'s cancel}}=\log_3(x+6)$$

Comment: What about when $x=6$?

Comment: That is not in domain as log(x-6) is not defined.

Comment: @Awesome That's exactly my point, since $x=6$ _is_ in the domain for the resulting equation.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of logarithms for division dictates that $$\log_b {m} - \log_b  n=\log_b \frac{m}{n}$$
for any base $b$ and any non-zero numbers $m,n$.

Substitute: $m = x^2-36$, $n=x-6$, and $b=3$. So

$$\log_3 (x^2-36) - \log_3(x-6)=\log_3 \frac{x^2-36}{x-6}=\log_3 \frac{(x+6)(x-6)}{x-6}=\log_3 (x+6)$$

Comment: What about when $x=6$?

Answer (score 2):

You applied the formula in a wrong way. The formula does not say that the difference of two logarithms is the quotient of the two logarithms. It says that the difference of two logarithms is the logarithm of the quotient of the two arguments !

Comment: By the way, if $\log(a)-log(b)=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$, that would mean that $A-B=\frac{A}{B}$ for any numbers !